# JavaScript save image after creating with drawImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get an image to automatically download after it has been created. I have this so far:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', main);

var img2 = loadImage('http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/peppers.jpg', main);
var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
        
        document.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    // http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called
    var img = new Image();
    
    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    return img;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="512" height="512" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The image is processed and created correctly but the download is not triggered and the following error message is displayed:

```
Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported
```

I have read up on the MDN doc on [CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) and have tried to set the `crossOrigin` to anonymous but that still doesn't work.

Is there a better method to use to trigger the download?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set image `crossOrigin` property before setting `src`.

Since you don't have access to the server the resources are on to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response headers, you're going to need a proxy.

I'm using `https://cors.io` for this answer but if you can use whichever does it for you.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('https://cors.io/?https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', main);


var img2 = loadImage('https://cors.io/?http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/peppers.jpg', main);
var imagesLoaded = 0;

function main() {
  imagesLoaded += 1;

  if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
    // composite now
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

    document.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
  // http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = onload;
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.src = src;

  return img;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="512" height="512" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but using a third part proxy site is great for dev, not so great for production

Comment: You can easily setup a backend to fetch the resource for yourself. I do have a thought though on using `fetch` to get the image resource, making a base64 blob of it and using that to set `img.src` to `data:image/gif;base64,...`. That may just work.